# How to improve the performance of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Problem decription:
There is an `int` array `nums` in which the elements are unordered.And there are no duplicate elements in `nums`.

`nums.length()` is known to have a range of [3,20000] and each element in `nums` has a range of [1,100000].

A combination `a`, `b`, `c` is a **good combination** when `nums[a]>=nums[b]>=nums[c]`, or `nums[a]<=nums[b]<=nums[c]`, and `0<=a<b<c<nums.length()`.

How do I find out how many **good combinations** there are in this array as quickly as possible?

Use Case 1:
Input `[1,2,3]`, output `1`
Explanation:
There is only one good combination `[1,2,3]`.

Use Case 2:
Input `[1,2,3,4]`, output `4`
Explanation:
There are four good combinations, which are
`[1,2,3]`
`[1,2,4]`
`[1,3,4]`
`[2,3,4]`

Here is the code implementation I wrote:

```java
public static long run(int[] params) {
    long count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < params.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < params.length; k++) {
                if (params[i] <= params[j] && params[j] <= params[k] ||
                        params[i] >= params[j] && params[j] >= params[k]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The performance of this code is too poor, because the time complexity is very high, how to optimize this code?

==================

The following is an optimization I tried, but the time complexity is still O(n^2).

```java
public static long run(int[] params) {
    int n = params.length;
    long count = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
        int leftLess = 0, leftMore = 0, rightLess = 0, rightMore = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (params[i] <= params[j]) {
                leftLess++;
            } else {
                leftMore++;
            }
        }
        for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            if (params[k] >= params[j]) {
                rightMore++;
            } else {
                rightLess++;
            }
        }
        count += leftLess * rightMore + leftMore * rightLess;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You don't improve the performance of this algorithm, you invent a completely different algorithm. (How do I improve the performance of a horse-drawn cart? First, get rid of the horse an use an ICE instead...)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in O(n log n) time.

For each possible *center* index `i`, you need to be able to calculate:

- `LL(i)`, the number of elements <= `params[i]` that are on the left of `A[i]`;
- `GL(i)`, the number of >= elements on the left;
- `LR(i)`, the number of <= elements on the right; and
- `GR(i)`, the number of >= elements on the right.

Then, for each `i`, `good_combos += LL(i) * GR(i) + GL(i) * LR(i)`.

As Kelly mentions in comments, however, this will double-count triplets where all 3 elements are the same, so these need to be subtracted:  `good_combos -= EL(i) * ER(i)`, where `EL` and `ER` are the number of equal elements on the left and right.  This can be calculated from what we already have: `EL(i) = LL(i) + GL(i) - i`, for example.

Each of the 4 values we need can be calculated in a similar way, so I'll only describe the procedure for calculating `LL`.  You can build an array of the `LL` values in O(n log n) time like this:

1. Sort all of the indexes by the value of their array elements.  Among equal elements, break ties to put smaller indexes first;
2. Iterate through the indexes in this order, adding each one to a [Fenwick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217104/simpler-alternatives-to-fenwick-trees/77225863#77225863) as you encounter it.
3. For each index `i`, extract the number of elements on its left from the Fenwick tree.  This is the value for `LL[i]`, because the iteration order ensures that all indexes for <= elements on the left have already been added to the tree, but no indexes for > elements have been added.

Comment: Wouldn't this compute 2 instead of 1 for input [6,6,6]?

Comment: Ah, yes, you have to subtract the number of all-equal triplets, which will get counted twice.  You can do it with the same information.  I've added some text to that effect.