# I need a function for a contiguous sub array that has a runtime complexity of n polylog n (Algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, big-o

I am doing an assignment with a group where we are supposed to make contiguous sub array, where we have a `tMin`, `tMax` where it gives us "pairs" for matches that fit in-between the min and the max. We have an input .txt file that it reads from and outputs the possible matches as an integer to a seperate output.txt file. The problem is that It wants us to go from O(n^2) to O(n polylog n)

```
import time

def number_of_allowable_intervals(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    # Open input file and read values
    with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file:
        # Read the size of the array and allowable range
        n, tmin, tmax = map(int, input_file.readline().strip().split(','))
        A = list(map(int, input_file.readline().replace(',', '').split()))

    # Count all subarrays within the range [tmin, tmax]
    sub_array_count = 0

    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(len(A)):
        current_sum = 0
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            current_sum += A[j]

            # Check if the sum is within the range [tmin, tmax]
            if tmin <= current_sum <= tmax:
                sub_array_count += 1

    end_time = time.time()


    print("Runtime:", end_time - start_time)

    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(str(sub_array_count))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_path = "input.txt"
    output_path = "output.txt"
    number_of_allowable_intervals(input_path, output_path)
```

This is the input.txt

```
10, 0, 0
-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1000
```

THe expected result should be 20.

This is what we have. We have tried to do binary search, we have tried to do AVLtrees, but we can't actually figure out a way to actually get it to work. We'd appreciate any help we can get. Please and thank you.

Edit....

> n the second problem, we are given only one array A[1, . . . , n], and a target value range
> [tmin, tmax]. We would like to count the number of non-empty contiguous subarrays of A that
> add up to a value in the range [tmin, tmax]. For example, if A = [−3, −4, 2, 0], tmin = −4
> and tmax = 3, then the output must be 7, since [−3], [−4], [2], [0], [−4, 2], [−4, 2, 0], and [2, 0] are contiguous subarrays of A with sum in the range [−4, 3], while [−3, −4], [−3, −4, 2],
> [−3, −4, 2, 0] are the other contiguous subarrays of A with sum outside this range. Design an
> O(n·polylog(n)) time algorithm for this problem. (Hint: Start with an O(n3) time algorithm,
> then reduce the running time to O(n2), and finally to O(n · polylog(n)). For the last step,
> consider using divide and conquer and the algorithm in part (1))

Comment: Pleas provide **exact** problem statement and some clear examples

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in O(n log n) time and O(n) space.

First, calculate the array `S` of prefix sums of `A`, such that `S[i]` is the sum of all `A[j]` such that `j < i`.  Note that `S.length == A.length+1`.

Now your task is to count all pairs `(i,j)` such that `j > i` and `tmin <= S[j]-S[i] <= tmax`.

Make an array `I` of all the indexes in `S` (i.e., all non-negative integers < S.length), and sort it by the corresponding value in `S`.

Now, iterate `for j in I`.  For each `j` the indexes `i` of all smaller sums such that `tmin <= S[j]-S[i] <= tmax` will be a contiguous subarray (window) in `I`.  The ends of this window move monotonically toward the end of `I`, and you can track them as you iterate in linear time.

Maintain a [Fenwick Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217104/simpler-alternatives-to-fenwick-trees/77225863#77225863) that contains all of the indexes `i` in the window as you iterate. For each `j`, query the tree to determine the number of smaller `i`s in the window.  This is the number of targeted pairs/subarrays that end at index `j`. Add this number to a running total.

When you're done, the running total is the count you seek.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(len(A)):
        current_sum = 0
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            current_sum += A[j] ...
```

Wow, that's a lot of re-computation going on,
considering that you never mutate `A`.

Compute the cumulative sums just once,
storing them in a scratch vector as you go.
Cost is O(N) linear.

Then use it as you scan, again with linear cost.
You may find the occasional judicious subtraction
will help you adapt those
[cached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)
results to your needs.