Solving box stacking problem in n log n, no rotations allowed
I need to solve a box stacking problem with the following rules:

Box is a tuple {x, y, height}.
You CAN NOT rotate boxes.
To stack a box b1 on top of another box b2, b1.x<=b2.x and b1.y<=b2.y.
Find maximum height, i.e. biggest possible sum of heights of stacked boxes.

I though about sorting boxes by a single axis (for example x-axis) and than to solve it like simple LIS problem with repsect to another axis(for example y-axis), but I have an issues doing so in n log n, as unlike in standard LIS, where length of a sequence is represented with index, here is must be represented with height of a box, which messes things up.
I tried to look algorithm up, but the issue is in the first condition, as all algorithms I have seen on the internet are based on the fact, that boxes can be rotated.
Examples:
Input: [(1,100,3),(2,1,100)]
Output: 100
Explanation: we can't place (1,100,3) on top of (2,1,100), as 100>1.
Similarly, we can't put (2,1,100) on top of (1,100,3), as 2 > 1.

Reading the problem I'm not too sure if the boxes are two dimensional and the height for optimization is simply the sum of y-values of the stack or if they are three dimensional and the optimized height should be in along a third axis. This would be cleared up immediately if you provided an example (array?) of boxes and reasoning for the optimal stacking for it and/or why.

@wLui155 Just redacted the question, and yes, the box is a 3 dimensional object, and we shall find the tallest possible tower of boxes.

Recognizing Appropriate Data Structure
For the easier problem where the y dimension could be ignored, it's a matter of sorting on the x dimension and applying a variant of the longest increasing subsequence problem (LIS).
However, with an extra y dimension to consider, even after sorting on x, it's necessary to do the following:

Efficiently get the largest sum of heights for all associated y less than or equal to the current box's y.
Update the maximal height with this box's y.

It turns out that the appropriate data structure that supports both of these operations in logarithmic time (on the space of ys) is a Binary Indexed Tree (BIT). From here, the problem is a modified version of LIS.
Code
Below's a Python3 implementation with a few test cases. solve_fast() is the function that determines the maximum attainable height the stack of boxes in N*log(N) time if N is the number of boxes and solve_slow() is a slower but in-theory correct algorithm. The BIT can be implemented any way you want and mine is pretty clunky. One trick you can do with the BIT is range compression on the y-values so that, if the possible domain on y is very big, the complexity of the BIT will still be relative the number of unique ys present instead.
from typing import List, Tuple

def solve_slow(boxes: List[Tuple[int, int, int]]) -> int:
    """
    Given list boxes where boxes[i] = [x, y, height] find the best selection/subset
    of boxes with maximal sum of height fields.

    A subset of boxes S is valid if...
    S[i].x <= S[i + 1].x and S[i].y <= S[i + 1].y for all indices i
    """
    N = len(boxes)
    s_boxes = sorted(boxes)
    best_by_y = [0] * (max(y for _, y, __ in boxes) + 1)
    for i, (x, y, height) in enumerate(s_boxes):
        best_par_height = 0
        for par_height in best_by_y[:y + 1]: # can look at y inclusive
            best_par_height = max(best_par_height, par_height)

        calc_height = height + best_par_height
        best_by_y[y] = calc_height

    return max(best_by_y)


class BIT:
    """
    BinaryIndexedTree designed for efficient updating of an array and
    querying the maximum value between any two indices in it
    """
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, left, right):
            """
            Assuming left <= right, the node needs to know the maximum value under its
            subtree and its two children
            """
            self._left, self._right = left, right
            self._lnode, self._rnode = None, None
            if left < right:
                mid = left + (right - left) // 2
                self._lnode =  BIT.Node(left, mid)
                self._rnode = BIT.Node(mid + 1, right)

            self._max = 0


        def get_max(self, left, right):
            if left < self._left and right > self._right:
                # this node is fully contained in the range
                return self._max

            if self._left == self._right: # single node
                return self._max

            # this node is not fully contained so look on lhs, rhs appropriately
            mid = self._left + (self._right - self._left) // 2
            if left <= mid and right > mid: # results will straddle this node
                return max(
                    self._lnode.get_max(left, mid),
                    self._rnode.get_max(mid + 1, right)
                )

            # left > mid or right <= mid...
            if left > mid: # then only look on right side
                return self._rnode.get_max(left, right)

            # only look on left
            return self._lnode.get_max(left, right)

        def update(self, idx, val):
            if self._left > idx or self._right < idx: # out of range
                return None

            if self._left == self._right: # then we're at the index
                self._max = val
                # print(f"updating single node {self._left} with {val}")
                return self._max

            # update appropriate child node
            mid = self._left + (self._right - self._left) // 2
            if idx <= mid: # update left
                left_val = self._lnode.update(idx, val)
                self._max = max(self._rnode._max, left_val)
                # print(f"{self._left} to {self._right} is {self._max}")
                return self._max

            # update right; there should
            right_val = self._rnode.update(idx, val)
            self._max = max(self._lnode._max, right_val)
            # print(f"{self._left} to {self._right} is {self._max}")
            return self._max


    def __init__(self, N):
        """
        assumes array is uniformly zero to begin with
        """
        self._root = BIT.Node(0, N)

    def query(self, left, right):
        """
        What's the maximum value in the subarray from left to right inclusive?
        Assumes left <= right
        """
        return self._root.get_max(left, right)

    def update(self, idx, val):
        """
        Simulate updating the array element at idx with val.
        Assumes idx is valid
        """
        return self._root.update(idx, val)


def solve_fast(boxes: List[Tuple[int, int, int]]) -> int:
    """
    Given list boxes where boxes[i] = [x, y, height] find the best selection/subset
    of boxes with maximal sum of height fields.

    A subset of boxes S is valid if...
    S[i].x <= S[i + 1].x and S[i].y <= S[i + 1].y for all indices i
    """
    # set up a BIT on the compressed y values for fast lookup/querying because BIT
    # allows for a fast max() operation on a subarray where the original array
    # can be modified live. compressing so that BIT complexity is relative to
    # number of y-terms as opposed to the space of potential y-values
    y_to_id, id_to_y = {}, []
    y_id = 0
    for y in sorted(y for _, y, __ in boxes):
        if y not in y_to_id:
            y_to_id[y] = y_id
            id_to_y.append(y)
            y_id += 1

    # print(y_to_id)
    # print(id_to_y)
    bit = BIT(len(id_to_y) - 1)

    # sorting lexicographically by x value gives us the x-condition
    # check for free when iterating in order
    res = 0
    for x, y, height in sorted(boxes):
        y_id = y_to_id[y]
        best_par_height = bit.query(0, y_id)
        # print(f"The best_par from {(0, y_id)} is {best_par_height}")
        calc_height = best_par_height + height
        res = max(res, calc_height)
        # print(calc_height)
        bit.update(y_id, calc_height)

    return res


def main():
    for boxes_id, boxes in enumerate([
        # test cases in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79278956/14789065 post + comments
        [
            (12, 15, 15),
            (4, 12, 11),
            (4, 12, 12),
            (8, 7, 5)
        ],
        [
            (50, 45, 20),
            (95, 37, 53),
            (45, 23, 12)
        ],
        [
            (7, 11, 17),
            (7, 17, 11),
            (11, 7, 17),
            (11, 17, 7),
            (17, 7, 11),
            (17, 11, 7)
        ],
        [
            (0, 2, 1),
            (1, 1, 100000)
        ]
    ]):
        r1, r2 = solve_slow(boxes), solve_fast(boxes)
        print(f"Test{boxes_id:<5}{r1:<10}{r2:<10}")

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

And it produces the below output:
Test0    38        38
Test1    65        65
Test2    35        35
Test3    100000    100000


You claim that using BIT will be faster.  However, you do not report the performance of the two methods.  So the claim is unsubstantiated.  I have my doubts that the extra complexity of BIT will provide a worthwhile  increase in execution speed.  I'd like to see some numbers.

Thank you  a lot! I knew that BIT could be the solution for this problem, however I could not understand how to actually use it in this case scenario, but now I do :) . I run my own tests on your code, and it is 100% success, which is pretty impressive I must say

@ravenspoint Well, after the compression on y coordinate, it is easy to see, that the length of an array under BIT is at most n. Any update or get functions are at most log2 n with respect to the size of BIT, and we use them only inside single for cycle over original array n, meaning the complexity is at most n log2 n with respect to the size of the input array. Any sorting also has complexity n log2 n, thus the complexity of the solution is n log n, which is as good as it can be.

My preference is to see the actual numbers from actual code running on actual problems.  It is easy to miss some unexpected bottleneck, or mis-implement a complex algorithm, and find the reality to be quite different.

I will concede that ravenspoint does have a good point about comparing the performance between the two methods with real data. Doing some very quick tests on random inputs that should degenerate into the worst-case performance (~10^4 boxes of equal x, y and heights up to 10^7) has the "slower" method finishing in a few seconds vs 20-30 seconds for the latter. Of course this could be due to my suboptimal implementation but I don't more cycles to spare for further analysis or improvement. Would be interested if a better BIT could make it edge out the asymptotically slower solution.

@ravenspoint As long as the question is for an algorithm and not for particular constant optimisation, faster and slower refers to asymptotic complexity, not runtime. There's a whole bunch of data structures accomplishing the same in O(n log n) total time, it's well-known that correctly written BIT has that complexity and any hypothetical mistakes in implementation aren't mistakes in algorithm. In addition, it'd be strange to benchmark sample implementation not intended for benchmarking. I can post my own efficient one or optimise this code if you'd like to see the comparison.

This is a good answer, but the Fenwick tree implementation is super complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217104/simpler-alternatives-to-fenwick-trees/77225863#77225863


We should sort the boxes by their first two dimensions (x, y) to ensure stacking order.
We append a new box to B if it fulfills all the conditions.
Finally, we output the sum of B's z, which is the maximum stack height.

Test
def get_max_height(boxes):
    boxes.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
    B = []
    for x, y, z in boxes:
        if not B or (x >= B[-1][0] and y >= B[-1][1]):
            B.append((x, y, z))

    return sum(z for _, _, z in B)


print(get_max_height([
    (12, 15, 15),
    (4, 12, 11),
    (4, 12, 12),
    (8, 7, 15)
]))

print(get_max_height([[50, 45, 20], [95, 37, 53], [45, 23, 12]]))
print(get_max_height([[7, 11, 17], [7, 17, 11], [11, 7, 17], [11, 17, 7], [17, 7, 11], [17, 11, 7]]))

Result
38
32
35


I don't really understand how does it solve box stacking problem. It finds a LIS of heights, and than sums them up, which is not even close to be the same as LIS of boxes. You have no gurantee than box a will be able to be stacked on box b. No to mention that height only signifies the value awarded to a tower.

@PavloShevchyk Updated. Since there is no rotation, this is just a sort problem. Right? You can also update your question with inputs and expected outputs for testing.

not really, see, you discard a box if it is not in dp, but if the first box is something like [0,inf,1] and the other is [1,1,10000], then the result of your algorithm is wrong.

@PavloShevchyk Just update your question with inputs and expected outputs. Someone will help you out. [0, INF, 1] is not a box. If you have that as an input, you need to update your question.

I don't see how it is not a box, as it is a valid three-tuple describing size of a box. The rules are really simple, so I don't see where your confusion is coming from.

@PavloShevchyk See this similar question with rotation and similarly add inputs and expected outputs. Someone will help you out.

[0, INF, 1] is not a box.  It is an infinite plane intersecting the Z axis at height 1.  It cannot be balanced on top of any box with finite dimensions.  Think of it as a tarpaulin rather than a box.
